Showing $\arctan\frac{a^2}{4z\sqrt{{z^2+a^2/2}}}=2\left(\arctan\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{2z^2}}\right)-\frac\pi4\right)$
I was working through problem $\bf 2.45$ of Griffiths and instead of the standard route of using the electric field of a square ring and integrating it out to a surface I went from first principles:

My answer for the electric field was
$$
\operatorname{E}\left(z\right) =
\frac{\sigma}{\pi\,\epsilon_{0}} \arctan\left(\,\frac{a^{2}}
{4z\,\sqrt{\,{z^{2} + a^{2}/2}\ }}\,\right)
\tag1$$

This agrees with other answers I've seen, however, the answer book states that
$$
\operatorname{E}\left(z\right) = \frac{2\sigma}{\pi \epsilon_0}\left[\arctan\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{2z^2}}\right) - \frac{\pi}{4}\right]
\tag2$$
and says that it is equal to my answer.


I cannot for the life of me figure out how though.
My attempts included changing the
$\pi/4$ into $\arctan\left(1\right)$
and using the $\arctan$ addition formula, the factor of $2$ is also strange but my guess was that I needed to use the following identity from Wikipedia:
$$
\arctan\left(x\right) = 2\arctan\left(\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)
\tag3$$
I have had no success in this approach.

Any help would be appreciated.
Graph:


The factor of. $2$. Is not strange. Start with the double angle formula for $\tan 2\theta$.  There seems to be an issue with signs, though. Your answer is an odd function, whereas theirs is even and has a sign error.

The function is only designed to be valid when z>0, this should clear up any odd and even problems I hope?

There remains an issue. As $z\to 0^+$, your answer tends to $\sigma/2\epsilon_0$, and theirs to $0$. Note that $\tan(\alpha-\pi/2) =-\cot\alpha$. They dropped a negative.

I don't quite see how their answer tends to 0: $2\sigma/\pi\epsilon_0[arctan(\infty) - \pi/4] = \sigma/2\epsilon_0?$

Hint:$$\tan(2\arctan u-\pi/2)=-\cot(2\arctan u)=\frac{u^2-1}{2u}.$$

Oh, right. My sloppiness. I still had a negative issue when I tried to check. Maybe another sloppiness.

Thank you for the hint J.G that solved it. Very thankful. Can I ask how you knew to use that one?

Your $z$-factor in $\left(,{\bf 1},\right)$ must be $\left\vert,{z},\right\vert$. I guess so. Unless, both are odd functions of $z$: In that case, the second must be multiplied by $\operatorname{sgn}\left(z\right)$.

How did I know? Oh, I just ignored the $\sigma/(\pi\epsilon_0)$ factor, then evaluated the book's answer.

Where can I find that identity that you hinted? I don't recognise it.

Graphically, they look FINE !!!


Interesting, that is a different graph to what I got(graph posted with question.)

You're missing a square root in the definition of $g$.

@Blue I’ll rerun the code. Thanks.

@Blue O k. I add the SQUARE ROOT I missed previously. Thanks a lot.

So, your $(3)$ comes from
$$
\frac{\tan\alpha}{1+\sqrt{1+\tan^2\alpha}}=\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}
$$
to simplify this quickly, denote
$$
\tan\alpha = \frac{\frac{a^2}{2z^2}}{2\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{2z^2}}} = \frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{1+\lambda}}
$$
hence
$$
\tan\frac{\alpha}{2} = \frac{\lambda}{2+\lambda+\sqrt{1+\lambda}} = \frac{\lambda}{(1+\sqrt{1+\lambda})^2} = \frac{\sqrt{1+\lambda}-1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda}+1}
$$
$$
\tan\beta = \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{2z^2}} = \sqrt{1+\lambda}
$$
easy to check that
$$
\tan\left(\beta-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) = \frac{\tan\beta-\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}}{1+\tan\beta\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}}=1
$$
and that is your identity.

First, simplify the problem letting $z=\frac{a }{\sqrt{2}}t$ to show (if true) that
$$\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2 t\sqrt{t^2+1}}\right)=2 \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}\right)-\frac{\pi }{2}$$ Use now
$$\tan ^{-1}(p)+\tan ^{-1}(q)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{p+q}{1-p\, q}\right)$$ to make
$$2 \tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}\right)=\tan ^{-1}\left(-2 t
   \sqrt{t^2+1}\right)=-\tan ^{-1}\left(2 t\sqrt{t^2+1}\right)$$ and continue.
If you are lazy, compare the Taylor series since, if it is an identity, it would be true for small angles.
